# DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL returns unexpected results

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know how many rows were added to a table in two time intervals: 1 hour, and 1 day. So I'm running these two `SQL` functions on `MySql`:

1 Day:

```
select count(*) 
    from table_name where DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 24 HOUR) < date;
```

1 Hour:

```
select count(*) 
    from table_name where DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 1 HOUR) < date;
```

The datatype of `date` is `timestamp`.

This seems trivial but what I see is that there are some 5000 rows per day, and about 600 rows per hour. I'm seeing this for a several days now, and I'm checking every couple of hours, so this result is what the database returns.

But this obviously doesn't make sense, as 600 * 24 is much larger than 5000.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there any possibility that you have future dated rows being inserted? E.g. if you have any rows with a `date` value for tomorrow, they'll be included in both counts.

Comment: (Also, obviously if `date` value can be updated, you'll get misleading results - so could that be possible?)

Comment: Check the distribution of the records per hour within a 24-hour period to see how the per hour distribution of record counts look like. It is your data, you need to do the analysis, we cannot explain this just based on a couple of syntactically correct queries!

Comment: check your clock definition, for example now() can show UTC timezone but the rows insert with local timezone